# What is the time complexity of the following algorithms, as a function of the number N of elements of mylist from position first to position last?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

```
def mystery(mylist, first, last):
     if (first == last):
        return mylist[first]
     mid = (first + last) // 2
     return min(mystery(mylist, first, mid), mystery(mylist, mid+1, last))
```

Is it $O(logN)$ because every time the array size becomes half and called again?

Comment: O(n), you halve the size of the array but you also double the invocations, basically canceling each other out.

Comment: You can get some hints just by doing some experiments with a counter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the time complexity of an algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-can-i-find-the-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: The `return mylist[first]` happens exactly N times, and the `return min(...)` statement happens exactly N-1 times. There's exactly 2N-1 calls to `mystery` (including the original call).

Comment: @Welbog no this doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can count exactly the operations in this function. First, one must observe that this function finds the smallest element in `mylist` between `first` and `last`.

We can see that `return mylist[first]` happens exactly once for each element of the input array, so happens exactly N times overall.

The second `return` (ie: `return min(...)`) chooses the smallest of the smallest of each half of the array. Each element in the array (except for the smallest element) is on the losing side of this `min` exactly once, so this statement occurs exactly N-1 times overall.

There's 2 calls to `mystery` for each execution of the second return statement, and none for the first return statement, and each call to `mystery` executes one or the other, so the total number of calls to `mystery` (including the initial call) is 1 + 2(N-1) = 2N-1.